# How to make ffmpeg exit when Input is broken

Tags: input, ffmpeg, exit, steam

I have written a bash script to keep a ffmpeg command up and running

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
    do

        echo `ffmpeg -re -i http://domain.com/index400.m3u8 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000?pkt_size=1316`
done
```

The problem is, sometimes the input is broken, yet ffmpeg does not exit when that happens so that it is restarted by the above script. Instead what happens is the same process is kept running eventhough it is not transferring any packet to the UDP address (output). And I need to manually go into the terminal and kill it (kill -9 #processID)

**I need a way to make ffmpeg kill its own process whenever the input is broken.**

Appreciate your help.

Comment: For `HTTP` you can set a timeout for socket I/O operations, eg. `http://example.com/..?timeout=3000000` (in microseconds). You can also check the input/output periodically. Do you have a specific case in which it hangs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't have a specific case, it happens virtually on a daily basis, but not in specific time, what happens if I add the timeout to the ingest ? 
and how can I check the output periodically to know that the stream is still being received ?